# Model in django to store working hours of an employee for specific year, month and week

Tags: mysql, sql-server, django

I am creating a Django application for online attendance system that has to store weekly working hours of employees for few years(5 or 6)

I want to create a table, that has employeeid, year, month, week and hours(example 4hrs for week1 in Jan 2015 for employee with id 200)

I tried creating models(year, month, week, record) with few ManyToManyFields and Foreignkey Fields, but ended up in creating tables that link years and employeeid, employeeid and month, years and month but not a table with the fields employeeid, week, month and year.

Could anyone tell me the relations between the fields to be used in models to create a database for this.
Thanx in advance

Here is my Models.py -

```
from django.db import models

class Month(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    weeks = models.ManyToManyField(Week, null = True)

class Year(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    month = models.ManyToManyField(Month, null = True)



class UserId(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 56) // employee name
    year = models.ForeignKey(Year, null = True)



class Week(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key =True, null = False)
    working_hours = models.IntegerField(null = True, default = 0)


class Record(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True, null = False)
    month = models.ManyToManyField(Month, null = True)
    year = models.ManyToManyField(Year, null = True)
    week = models.ManyToManyField(Week, null=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(UserId, null = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This model will satisfy your requirements

**Note:** you don't have to create primary key(id) field, it will be automatically created by django.

```
from django.db import models


class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 56)


class Record(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    month = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField()
    week = models.IntegerField()
    hours = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('employee', 'month', 'year', 'week'),)
```